# Fody: An unhandled exception has occured

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I recently tried to build a xamarin project and got a `Project.dll.mdb` not found error. I solved this by updating to the latest version of `Xamarin.Forms`. Now I get this new error I suspect is relate to pdb and mdb:

```
MSBUILD : error : Fody: An unhandled exception occurred:
MSBUILD : error : Exception:
MSBUILD : error : Index was outside the bounds of the array.
MSBUILD : error : StackTrace:
MSBUILD : error :   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.BitAccess.ReadInt32 (System.Int32& value) [0x00000] in <d39e61ae2787473a851567b860d13696>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.BitAccess.ReadInt32 (System.Int32[] values) [0x00004] in <d39e61ae2787473a851567b860d13696>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.MsfDirectory..ctor (Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbReader reader, Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFileHeader head, Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.BitAccess bits) [0x000ae] in <d39e61ae2787473a851567b860d13696>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFunctions (System.IO.Stream read, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.UInt32,Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbTokenLine]& tokenToSourceMapping, System.String& sourceServerData, System.Int32& age, System.Guid& guid) [0x00027] in <d39e61ae2787473a851567b860d13696>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at Mono.Cecil.Pdb.PdbReader.PopulateFunctions () [0x00008] in <d39e61ae2787473a851567b860d13696>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at Mono.Cecil.Pdb.PdbReader.ProcessDebugHeader (Mono.Cecil.Cil.ImageDebugDirectory directory, System.Byte[] header) [0x00048] in <d39e61ae2787473a851567b860d13696>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ProcessDebugHeader () [0x00012] in <b5a52cab1f0046ce9f68342127787868>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadSymbols (Mono.Cecil.Cil.ISymbolReader reader) [0x00015] in <b5a52cab1f0046ce9f68342127787868>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00047] in <b5a52cab1f0046ce9f68342127787868>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModuleFrom (Mono.Cecil.PE.Image image, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00076] in <b5a52cab1f0046ce9f68342127787868>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00028] in <b5a52cab1f0046ce9f68342127787868>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x0000a] in <b5a52cab1f0046ce9f68342127787868>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at InnerWeaver.ReadModule () [0x00054] in <1733edda69ed46a983dfb90261345c6a>:0 
MSBUILD : error :   at InnerWeaver.Execute () [0x00019] in <1733edda69ed46a983dfb90261345c6a>:0 
MSBUILD : error : Source:
MSBUILD : error : Mono.Cecil.Pdb
MSBUILD : error : TargetSite:
MSBUILD : error : Void ReadInt32(Int32 ByRef)
MSBUILD : error :
```

I'm very new at Xamarin, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbReader" would suggest me to clean solution, delete bin and obj folder and recompile

Comment: I did this, still getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes I have errors with PropertyChanged.Fody (I don't know if it's the "Fody" you are using). Removing the package and reinstalling it, error should disappear

Comment: Yeah, had an old version of `PropertyChanged.Fody` updating which solved the error. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!